# XAML Binding from within a element-property will not work

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, properties, element

I could maybe do the description in the header a bit better.

This is the scenario.

I have got a Class RecordNavigationDescriptor which inherits from DependencyObject. Inside there's a Dependency Property which in this scope we will call it 'MyObject'.

I want to assign this Object to the tag Property of my User Control. I want that the 'MyObject' dp should point to one of the controls of my User Control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Exchange"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" FontSize="72" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Text="Testing...."/>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
        <Grid.Tag>
            <local:RecordNavigationDescriptor MyObject="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock}"  FriendlyName="Testing... Testing..."/>
        </Grid.Tag>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This Binding will not work. So, 'MyObject' will be Null.

However,

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Exchange"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" FontSize="72" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Text="Testing...."/>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
        <local:RecordNavigationDescriptor MyObject="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock}" FriendlyName="Testing... Testing..."/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This will work.

So, what is the cause of the problem?

Will I have to instantiate my RecordNavigationDescriptor object as a static resource? and then assign it to the Tag propery?